# Python compression list and filter

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have these two exercises, I wouldn't like you to give me the code solved itself, but to know how could I understand these kind of problems.

First one: (Using compression list)

```
lst = [(1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8,9)]
desired result: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I just noticed I could do something like

```
print( [ x for x in lst[0] ] )
```

so I got `[1,2]`

where 0 could be n, and I would get the other tuples.But I don't get how to use that for a range of tuples. (For all them)

Second one: In a dict get those who in each key, the sum of all values is > 10

```
lst  = { 0: [3,6,4], 1: [1,1,2], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 4: [1,3,3], 5: [4,4,6] }
desired result: { 0: [3,6,4], 2: [3,5,3], 3: [1,7,4], 5: [4,4,6] }
```

In this one I'm so lost... I tried something like

```
dict(filter(lambda e: sum(e[1]) > 10, lst.items()))
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Comment: why is `4: [1,3,3]` in your desired result in the second example? I get `{0: [3, 6, 4], 2: [3, 5, 3], 3: [1, 7, 4], 5: [4, 4, 6]}` which seems correct.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong, updated, thanks! @MarkMeyer